Vscode port forwarding is reloading without any reason when using vite
I am trying to view my webpage on ipad so I am using the port forwarding. The page opens correctly and even functions but automatically reloads after a few seconds. Here are logs which I get before the reload
WebSocket connection to 'wss://pp3w747r-3001.inc1.devtunnels.ms:3001/' failed: 
(anonymous) @ client:188Understand this error
[vite] server connection lost. polling for restart...
Navigated to https://pp3w747r-3001.inc1.devtunnels.ms/
client.ts:16 [vite] connecting...

I have tried many ways. I think this problem is related to vite in someway. I have tried chaning my vite config hmr a lot(disable and other stuff) but nothing worked. Also there is no github issue or anything else related to this issue.
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import dts from "vite-plugin-dts";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
   plugins: [
      react(),

      dts({
         include: [
            "src/**/*.ts",
            "src/**/*.d.ts",
            "src/**/*.d.tsx",
            "src/**/*.tsx",
         ], // Adjust patterns as necessary
         exclude: ["node_modules/**", "**/*.spec.ts"], // Exclude unnecessary files
         outDir: "dist",
         insertTypesEntry: true,
      }),
   ],
   server: {
      host: "0.0.0.0",
      port: 3001,
      hmr: false,
      watch: { usePolling: false },
   },
   build: {
      lib: {
         entry: "src/main.tsx", // Path to your library's entry point
         name: "MyLib",
         formats: ["es", "umd", "cjs"],
         fileName: (format) => `index.${format}.js`,
      },
      rollupOptions: {
         // Externalize dependencies to avoid bundling them into your library
         external: ["react", "react-dom"],
         output: {
            // Provide globals for externalized dependencies
            globals: {
               react: "React",
               "react-dom": "ReactDOM",
            },
         },
      },
   },
});

Here is my vite config. Any help or guidance is appreciated.
Note: I am using windows 10
